# Header-only generic console menu maker

Tags: c++, console, c++17

Some time ago, I wrote [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/176644/39848) to a question about creating a command line menu.  I referred to it [recently](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253644/grade-calculator-new-oop-version-from-one-previous/253648#253648) and noticed a few things that I wanted to improve.

### Purpose

As with the original version, the purpose is to have a class which simplifies the construction and use of a command line (console) menu.

The improvements I made are:

1. allow either `std::string` or `std::wstring` prompts and answers
2. allow the user to separate selectors from descriptions
3. move everything into a header-only module
4. allow creation of `const` menus
5. sort by selectors

### Questions

Some things I had questions about are:

1. template parameter names - could they be improved?
2. use of `default_in` and `default_out` - would it be better to infer defaults from the string type?
3. choice of `std::function<void()>` as the operation for each choice
4. use of `std::pair` vs. custom object
5. should I wrap all of this in a namespace?
6. is any functionality missing?
7. is there a way to make a `constexpr` version?

### menu.h

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> struct default_in;

template<> struct default_in<std::istream> { 
    static std::istream& value() { return std::cin; }
};

template<> struct default_in<std::wistream> { 
    static std::wistream& value() { return std::wcin; }
};

template <typename T> struct default_out;

template<> struct default_out<std::ostream> { 
    static std::ostream& value() { return std::cout; }
};

template<> struct default_out<std::wostream> { 
    static std::wostream& value() { return std::wcout; }
};

template <class str, class intype, class outtype>
class ConsoleMenu {
  public:
    ConsoleMenu(const str& message,
        const str& invalidChoiceMessage,
        const str& prompt,
        const str& delimiter,
        const std::map<str, std::pair<str, std::function<void()>>>& commandsByChoice,
        intype &in = default_in<intype>::value(),
        outtype &out = default_out<outtype>::value());
    void operator()() const;
  private:
    outtype& showPrompt() const;
    str message;
    str invalidChoiceMessage_;
    str prompt;
    str delimiter;
    std::map<str, std::pair<str, std::function<void()>>> commandsByChoice_;
    intype &in;
    outtype &out;
};

template <class str, class intype, class outtype>
ConsoleMenu<str, intype, outtype>::ConsoleMenu(const str& message,
    const str& invalidChoiceMessage,
    const str& prompt,
    const str& delimiter,
    const std::map<str, std::pair<str, std::function<void()>>>& commandsByChoice,
    intype &in, outtype& out) :
        message{message},
        invalidChoiceMessage_{invalidChoiceMessage},
        prompt{prompt},
        delimiter{delimiter},
        commandsByChoice_{commandsByChoice},
        in{in}, 
        out{out} 
{}

template <class str, class intype, class outtype>
outtype& ConsoleMenu<str, intype, outtype>::showPrompt() const {
    out << message;
    for (const auto &commandByChoice : commandsByChoice_) {
      out << commandByChoice.first 
            << delimiter
            << commandByChoice.second.first
      << '\n';
    }
    return out << prompt;
}

template <class str, class intype, class outtype>
void ConsoleMenu<str, intype, outtype>::operator()() const {
    str userChoice;
    const auto bad{commandsByChoice_.cend()};
    auto result{bad};
    out << '\n';
    while (showPrompt() && (!(std::getline(in, userChoice)) ||
            ((result = commandsByChoice_.find(userChoice)) == bad))) {
        out << '\n' << invalidChoiceMessage_;
    }
    result->second.second();
}

#endif // MENU_H
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "menu.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <class str, class outtype>
class Silly {
public:
    void say(str msg) {
        default_out<outtype>::value() << msg << "!\n";
    }
};

using MySilly = Silly<std::string, std::ostream>;

int main() {
    bool running{true};
    MySilly thing;
    auto blabble{std::bind(&MySilly::say, thing, "BLABBLE")};
    const ConsoleMenu<std::string, std::istream, std::ostream> menu{
        "What should the program do?\n",
        "That is not a valid choice.\n",
        "> ",
        ". ",
        {
            { "1", {"bleep", []{ std::cout << "BLEEP!\n"; }}},
            { "2", {"blip", [&thing]{ thing.say("BLIP"); }}},
            { "3", {"blorp", std::bind(&MySilly::say, thing, "BLORP")}},
            { "4", {"blabble", blabble }},
            { "5", {"speak Chinese", []{std::cout << "对不起，我不能那样做\n"; }}},
            { "0", {"quit", [&running]{ running = false; }}},
        }
    };
    while (running) {
        menu();
    }
}
```

This shows the use of the program and several different ways of creating menu functions.  Depending on your console and compiler settings, the Chinese sentence may or may not be displayed properly.  Next is a wide string version.

### wide.cpp

```
#include "menu.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <locale>

template <class str, class outtype>
class Silly {
public:
    void say(str msg) {
        default_out<outtype>::value() << msg << "!\n";
    }
};

using MySilly = Silly<std::wstring, std::wostream>;

int main() {
    bool running{true};
    MySilly thing;
    auto blabble{std::bind(&MySilly::say, thing, L"BLABBLE")};
    ConsoleMenu<std::wstring, std::wistream, std::wostream> menu{
        L"What should the program do?\n",
        L"That is not a valid choice.\n",
        L"> ",
        L". ",
        {
            { L"1", {L"bleep", []{ std::wcout << L"BLEEP!\n"; }}},
            { L"2", {L"blip", [&thing]{ thing.say(L"BLIP"); }}},
            { L"3", {L"blorp", std::bind(&MySilly::say, thing, L"BLORP")}},
            { L"4", {L"blabble", blabble }},
            { L"5", {L"说中文", []{std::wcout << L"对不起，我不能那样做\n"; }}},
            { L"0", {L"quit", [&running]{ running = false; }}},
        }
    };
    std::locale::global(std::locale{"en_US.UTF-8"});
    while (running) {
        menu();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps more event driven and model-view-controller like architecture would be better? Usually there is some shared state that needs to change and there is usually only one screen to render into. Perhaps I’m being biased towards OpenGL though.

Comment: It could have been separated, but there's so little of the view and controller pieces that it didn't seem worthwhile to do that.  Also keep in mind that one could easily wrap this inside another `class` to maintain whatever shared state might be needed.  The `running` variable was intended to illustrate that kind of use.

Comment: The use cases I had in mind were multi-menu situations and submenu cases. There are also conditions when menu needs to be rebuilt or some parts of it disabled. For example not letting the user exit without explicitly either saving or discarding current state.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  I had in mind a simple single-level menu that was small and simple enough to be useable on an embedded system.  An answer pointing out the use case you mention and what is lacking in the current code to support it would be welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answers to your questions

> template parameter names - could they be improved?

Mostly it's that they are inconsistent. Start type names with a capital, and either suffix them all with `Type` or don't. I suggest:

- `str` -> `Str`
- `intype` -> `IStream` (just to be clear the we do expect something like `std::istream` here)
- `outtype` -> `OStream`

> use of default_in and default_out - would it be better to infer defaults from the string type?

Yes, see below.

> choice of `std::function<void()>` as the operation for each choice

You need `std::function<>` here to store the functions for each choice in the map. The only question is if `void()` is the right type for the function. If you wanted `operator()()` to take parameters and/or return a value, then you would have to change the type of the function as well.

> use of std::pair vs. custom object

I personally think it's fine with `std::pair`.

> should I wrap all of this in a namespace?

If it is just `class ConsoleMenu`, I don't think it would be any improvement to put it in a namespace. However, I would put `default_in` and `default_out` in a namespace, as those names are quite generic, and you don't want them to pollute the global namespace.

> is any functionality missing?

I don't know, if this is all you need then it's complete. If you need something else from it, it's not.

> is there a way to make a constexpr version?

Yes, by making sure it satisfies the requirements of [LiteralType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType). This also means that all member variables must be valid LiteralTypes, and that prevents using `std::string` or `std::map`. You can use `const char *` and `std::array` instead.

## Pass the input and output stream by value

The construction you have where you pass a stream type as a template parameter, and then have it deduce a concrete stream from that is very weird, inflexible, and requires more typing than necessary. Just add the input and output stream as parameters to the constructor:

```
template <class str, class intype, class outtype>
class ConsoleMenu {
public:
    ConsoleMenu(const str& message,
        ...,
        intype &in,
        outtype &out);
```

Compare:

```
ConsoleMenu<std::wstring, std::wistream, std::wostream> menu{...}
```

Versus:

```
ConsoleMenu<std::wstring> menu{..., std::wcin, std::wcout}
```

If you want the standard input and output to be a default parameter, then I would deduce it from the string type:

```
template <typename T> struct default_in;

template<> struct default_in<std::string> { 
    static std::istream& value() { return std::cin; }
};

template<> struct default_in<std::wstring> { 
    static std::wistream& value() { return std::wcin; }
};

...

template <class str, class intype, class outtype>
class ConsoleMenu {
public:
    ConsoleMenu(const str& message,
        ...,
        intype &in = default_in<str>::value(),
        outtype &out = default_out<str>::value());
```

Because then you can just write:

```
ConsoleMenu menu{L"Wide menu", L"invalid", L"> ", L". ", {/* choices */}};
```

Comment: I also noticed another flaw with my version.  If I try to use `std::string_view`, the code won't compile because it tries to read one from `std::cin`.  I think I'll have to key the type off of the string type such that `wstring_view` becomes `wstring`.  Still pondering how best to do that.

Comment: You could use `str::value_type` perhaps? And then use `intype = std::basic_istream<str::value_type>` as the default parameter value.